# how to know what javascript is call when click a button in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I used the element inspect tool in chrome to inspect the button, the element is

```
<div class="TabText">start</div>
```

But that "start" is really clickable. Then I open the page source, and search "start", but can't find the "start" word. What's the possible cause that I could find "start" in element inspector, but not in page source? and is there any tool in chrome to know what js function(I guess it called some js function) it called?

Comment: have you any js code in your page?

Comment: This could happen due to several reasons. An element containing this element has an `onclick` attribute bound to JavaScript. Or the page uses jquery to bind the `onclick` event. It's hard to say anything without seing the code. If your page is online you can give us a link to take a look. Or consider creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Most likely the code that performs the function of that element is in another file looks something like this in the head <script type="text/javascript" src="FILE_NAME.js"></ script>

Comment: *"is there any tool in chrome to know what js function(I guess it called some js function) it called?"* -- You can add breakpoints and track the JavaScript in the "Sources" tab of the Chrome Dev-Tools (CTRL+SHIFT+C)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to create a function in Javascript and write inside the tag `onclick="youfunction"`

```
<div class="TabText" onclick="hi()">start</div>
```

And the function

```
function hi(){
}
```

has to declared inside the tag `<script type="text/javascript">`

Or if you have the particular function already defined you have to use **Inspect Element** (you can call with right-click on page) and you use the debugger or **Firebug** (tools/add-ons of Chrome) and you use the script.

how to know what javascript is call when click a button in chrome?
Then you use **Inspect Element**, use debugger, check you script and observe....